# Multiple Tables saved in the same .fits file

Tags: python, astropy, fits, pyfits

I have multiple tables created with `astropy.table.Table`, for example:

```
 from astropy.table import Table
 import numpy as np
 #table 1
 ta=Table()
 ta["test1"]=np.arange(0,100.)
 #table 2
 tb=Table()
 tb["test2"]=np.arange(0,100.)
```

I can save them individually to `.fits` files using

```
ta.write('table1.fits')
tb.write('table2.fits')
```

But I would like to have them saved to the same `.fits` file, each of them with a different `hdu`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example of how to do this [here](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/#creating-a-new-table-file). So, you could do something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits

ta = Table()
ta['test1'] = np.arange(0, 100.)
col1 = fits.Column(name=ta.colnames[0], format='E', array=ta)

tb = Table()
tb['test2'] = np.arange(0, 100.)
col2 = fits.Column(name=tb.colnames[0], format='E', array=tb)

cols = fits.ColDefs([col1, col2])

hdu = fits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(cols)
hdu.writeto('table.fits')
```

which only has one binary table HDU, but with two columns. Alternatively, to add them as separate HDUs, you could do something like

```
ta = Table()
ta['test1'] = np.arange(0, 100.)
col1 = fits.Column(name=ta.colnames[0], format='E', array=ta)

hdu1 = fits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(fits.ColDefs([col1]))

tb = Table()
tb['test2'] = np.arange(0, 100.)
col2 = fits.Column(name=tb.colnames[0], format='E', array=tb)

hdu2 = fits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(fits.ColDefs([col2]))

# create a header
hdr = fits.Header()
hdr['Author'] = 'Me'
primary_hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(header=hdr)

# put all the HDUs together
hdul = fits.HDUList([primary_hdu, hdu1, hdu2])

# write it out
hdul.writeto('table.fits')
```

Comment: But this example creates a `.fits`  table that include the two tables as part of the same table. Even though in my simplified example I gave examples of two tables with one column, building a table with two columns based on the simpler one is not what I want. As I said in the question, I want to build a `.fits` file with each table in one hdu.

Comment: @JuliaRoquette - I've edited the answer to hopefully do what you require. Does the edited answer help?

Comment: the edited answer help, yes. But there is a small miss-spell on it which produces an error: I checked on pyfits and the right name for the module is `ColDefs` instead of `ColsDef` that you wrote.

Comment: @Christoph's solution is a bit neater than mine, so I'd recommend that

Comment: You don't necessarily need all this stuff either: `hdu1 = fits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(fits.ColDefs([col1]))`  Much of the manual construction of FITS table structures can be simplified for example by using [Table.as_array()](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.table.Table.html#astropy.table.Table.as_array), since `BinTableHDU.from_columns` accepts a multi-field Numpy array.  So `BinTableHDU.from_columns(table.as_array())` works here (I think that's what `table_to_hdu()` is mostly doing as well).

Answer (score 5):

There's a utility function [astropy.io.fits.table_to_hdu](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/api/tables.html#table-to-hdu).

To continue your example if you have two table objects `ta` and `tb`:

```
from astropy.io import fits
hdu_list = fits.HDUList([
    fits.PrimaryHDU(),
    fits.table_to_hdu(ta),
    fits.table_to_hdu(tb), 
])
hdu_list.writeto('tables.fits')
```